# An internal error occurred during: "Processing Acceleo changes since last activation"

Tags: eclipse, uml, acceleo

I installed Acceleo 3.3 on Eclipse Indigo (from the update site) and when I launch Eclipse I get the following message:

An internal error occurred during: "Processing Acceleo changes since last activation".
org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace.addSaveParticipant(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ISaveParticipant;)Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/ISavedState;

This doesn't prevent Eclipse to start but when I want to create an Acceleo Project, I don't see neither http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML (as indicated in the Getting started tutorial) nor any URI containing the word 'UML' in the metamodel URIs list. When I choose another URI, I get the error UML2 is not installed.

Any help please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the UML project from the Eclipse update site. You need to go to Help -> Install New Software -> use the update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo (if I remember correctly) then go in the modeling section to select UML Extender SDK and install it.